# Combining & averaging magnetometer values

Tags: arduino-uno, magnetometer

I am trying to measure a users 'hand steadiness' in order to control a video game character in UNITY3D. I am using a MinIMU-9 Gyro/Accelerometer/Compass linked with Arduino. I can measure pitch/roll etc in Arduino...and I have passed previous Arduino measurements into Unity via the serial command but I am l trying to do two things:
1. simplify & reduce noise in the data coming from the magnetometer reading before I pass it into Unity by taking an average of every 10 magnetometer readings.
2. Combining the three magnetometer values to get one overall variable or measurement that can be passed into unity.

This is the demo Sketch I have but I'm not sure how to script the addition of the x,y,z magnetometer values:

```cpp
#include <Wire.h>
#include <LSM303.h>
LSM303 compass;
char report[80];
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Wire.begin();
  compass.init();
  compass.enableDefault();
}
void loop()
{
  compass.read();
  snprintf(report, sizeof(report), "A: %6d %6d %6d    M: %6d %6d %6d",
    compass.a.x, compass.a.y, compass.a.z,
    compass.m.x, compass.m.y, compass.m.z);
  Serial.println(report);
  delay(100);
}
```

This is the type of 'averaging script' I would like to add in somewhere but I'm not sure where exactly to place it:

```cpp
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){    //take ten readings in ~0.02 seconds
    reading[i] = compass.m.y;
    delay(2);
  }
  for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++){   //average the ten readings
    finalMagYreading += reading[i];
  }
   finalMagYreading
 /= 10;
```

Any help with this would be great.

Comment: Also consider a rolling average where you take eg New_AVG = 10% x latest_reading  + 90% of Old_AVG. (Or 1/N of reading + (N-1)/N of old value for N samples. ) This behaves rather differently than you may expect and is smoother than just averaging N samples. Easyish to implement. | OLD=AVG; AVG = OLD x (n-1)/N + Sample/n .

Comment: Thanks Russell - I managed to use a Unity plugin to use the accelerometer in my android phone to remotely control the virtual object on my main monitor in Unity. I would now like to trigger an event based on a rapid rotational change on the y axis. 
Is it possible to compare one realtime accelerometer reading against the same variable reading .2 seconds later? Something like:

'if ((euler.y) >= (euler.y)+30);
   {
    GUI.Label(Rect(150,150,200,150),"high tilt", largeFont);
    }'

Comment: The later comparison sounds like a standard operation unless I am missing something. Save current value as eg OldValue. Then compare with current value 200 mS later. In a multi function system use eg millis() to determine when 200 ms is up. |One off save: ActionTime = 200 + millis(); Then in loop if (millis() >= ActionTime) { ....}